# vscode/LSP: debugging vscode extension using breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml, language-server-protocol

i'm trying to implement vscode extension which is language client (written in typescript) that communicates with LSP server which is written in OCaml. for that, i need to debug my extension step by step using breakpoints i read the documentation but it doesn't help so much.